# using function outside the shiny app which uses reactive function as an argument

Tags: r, shiny

I have created the following reprex which tries to use a reaction function price() outside the shiny app as an argument of the function.
When i try to input the values which come out of a function in a variable it doesn't seem to work. It says 'Error in myfunction(argument1) : object 'argument1' not found '.
I want to use the reactive values outside of the shiny app but i am not able to do that

```
library(shiny)

# in script.R
myfunction <- function(argument1){
    return(as.numeric(argument1))
}
f<-myfunction(argument1)  #Trying to put output values in a variable

# in app.R
#source("script.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("price", "Price", value=1, min=1 , max=10)
    ,textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    price <- reactive(myfunction(argument1 = input$price))
    output$text<- renderText(price())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When you're calling `myfunction(argument1)` in line 7, the object `argument1` does not exist anywhere, hence the error.

Comment: How can i use a reactive function outside the shiny app in a script?

Comment: What does outside the app mean? Do you need to access the current value of reactive input e.g. from another program / process? Functions are not reactive, values are.

Comment: You can't access "stuff" from the shiny app outside of it's scope. You can have a script that refers to functions/values, but those should be sources from the `server()` function.